# What is the best word to translate passport for traveling abroad?

Tags: single-word-requests

We have two types of passports in our country: internal and for traveling abroad. How can I specify that I have passport for traveling abroad? That's not to be called foreign passport and I'm not sure about international passport. What would you suggest?

Comment: I'd suggest "passport" for international travel and some other word for the internal document. Which country are you from, and what do you call the two documents?

Comment: I'm from Ukraine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe the accepted term is "international passport".

In most countries, no passport is needed for travel within the country, and so the only kind of passport is an international passport, and so it is called simply a "passport".

Answer (score 0):

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ukrainian_passport):

> The Ukrainian passport is a document issued to the nationals of Ukraine as the main proof of Ukrainian citizenship. There are two types of passport issued by the Ukrainian government that
>   are commonly known as internal passport and international passport. An internal passport is used as a primary identification document of
>   Ukrainian citizens within Ukraine. An international
>   passport is used for international travel.

Most countries only have international passports, which are simply called passports, so unless you need to specifically disambiguate the terms for your reader, you can just use the word *passport*.

Comment: See also: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internal_passport